# Slaying the Circular Dependence

Tags: c++, c++11

I'm having a problem compiling with circular dependencies. I did some research, and people recommended using a forward declaration. I'm still having a problem with that because the class that has a forward declaration is using methods from the forwarded class. This causes the compiler to give me the error "Class A has incomplete field b". How can I get around the circular dependency where A requires B, and B requires A?

A.h:

```
#ifndef A_H_
#define A_H_

#include <iostream>
//#include "B.h"

class A
{
    class B;
    private:
        B b;
    public:
        A();
        ~A();
        void method();
};
#endif
```

A.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "A.h"

A::A()
{
}

A::~A()
{
}

void A::method()
{
    b.method();
}
```

B.h:

```
#ifndef B_H_
#define B_H_

#include <iostream>
//#include "A.h"

class B
{
    class A;
    private:
        A a;
    public:
        B();
        ~B();
        void method();
};
#endif
```

B.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "B.h"

B::B()
{
}

B::~B()
{
}

void B::method()
{
    a.method();
}
```

Comment: So an object `A` contains a `B`, which contains an `A`, which contains a `B`, which contains an `A`, which contains a `B`...

Comment: You can't have `A` within `B` and `B` within `A`. What you can do is have a pointer to A within B or pointer to B within A

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will not work as you have constructed it as `A` requires full knowledge *of the size of `B`* and `B` requires the same of `A`, which is only given by seeing the full declaration.

The following is not valid:

```
class B;
class A {
   B b;
};
```

Why?  How much space do we allocate for an instance of `A`?  `sizeof(A) = sizeof(B) = undefined` There is a workaround, however:

```
class B;
class A {
    B* b_ptr;
    B& b_ref;
};
```

This is perfectly valid, since the pointer and reference's size are known, regardless of the type they point to.

Answer (score 7):

Your classes cannot work. Every `A` contains a `B`, which contains an `A`, which contains a `B`, etc., ad infinitum.

Answer (score 3):

In at least one case (either `A` or `B`) you have to remove the dependence on the complete type.  For example, below I've removed the need for `A` to have the complete type of `B` within the `A.h` header file:

```
// A.h
class B;

// B used as a reference only, so the complete type
// is not needed at this time
class A
{
public:
   A(B& b) : b_(b) {}

   void method();

private:
   B& b_;
};

// A.cpp
// B is used, and the complete type is required
#include "B.h"

void A::f()
{
   b.method();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could try to replace one of the member by a pointer to the other class :

```
class B;
class A
{
    private:
        B* b;
    public:
        A();
        ~A();
        void method();
};
```